# Android Multi Touch Sensors Programming

Tags: java, android, touch, multi-touch

I've got a question with regard to the hardware of Android mobile phones.
Do they have multiple touch sensors?

Is it possible to make two buttons that can be pressed at the same time?

For example, I'm programming a ping-pong game and I'm creating a multiplayer mode (face to face IRL). However if player 1 is touching the screen to change the direction of the racket, then player 2 can't make his racket change direction because a button is already pressed. How to solve this?

Comment: The first search entry for 'android multitouch' is: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html

Comment: But is it possible to do this on ImageButtons? To implement onTouchListener and then set a common touch listener for all buttons. Then I can handle all different exceptions from there? That got a little messy sorry, I don't know how to explain it but it doesn't work at the moment, at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, two components can be pressed at the same time and you can get multiple callbacks from those events in screen too as shown below:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    //Make sure is multi-touch...
    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
        int pointerId = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK;
        int actionEvent = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        //At this point you know the id of the touch event and what action just happened.
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

For multiple events on buttons you don't really have to worry about the touch events, if both buttons have click listeners set, those listeners will be triggered automatically. "IMPORTANT": Before Honeycomb there was no support for multiple buttons pressed at the same time, so if your targetSDK is below Honeycomb you will get only one click event and the other one will be ignored, change the targetSDK and you should be fine.

Also this post explains exactly how to do it:
http://www.doepiccoding.com/blog/?p=250

Hope it Helps!

Regards!

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin Cazares!

Comment: Sure, if it was helpful please don't forget to mark it as correct so people will take time to answer your questions later on.

Comment: Regarding multiple buttons: Do I need several onClickListeners instead of implementing one big method that handles all buttons in a switch case?  PS: Will accpet the answer in 3 mins (time left) ;)

Comment: That's really up to you, usually different methods bring to more readable and clean code, but if you think is worth it to have all of them in the same method and switching the functonality, well that's up to the programmer...

Comment: It is at min. API level 15 and target API level 21. Should I implements an onTouchListener for the buttons and do as you described in the answer instead?

Comment: No, if you are setting the click listeners in both buttons it should be enough

Comment: But if I press one of the buttons (and don't release it), no other button can be pressed and which should result in a direction change...

Comment: could you boost the minSDK to 17 and try again? also are you sure the device you are testing on handles multiple touches?

Comment: My LG Optimus L9 handles 10 multitouches so yes it does.

Comment: Hey! Now it works great :D I don't know why but I'm glad it does. Thanks again for all your help and support although I've been a bit retarded on the way ;)